# How to show a custom floating option menu in onLongPress and hold item of recyclerView?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I am trying to achieve this view in my native android app in **item long-press** from the list  :

[image: Floating option menu in item long press]

My list is:

```
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
          android:id="@+id/chatList"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
          app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
          app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
          app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/chat_toolbar" />
```

List initialization java code:

```
RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(ChatList.this);
    chatList.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    chatList.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    chatList.setAdapter(chatAdapter);
```

Answer (score 1):

**You can use android's** [Popup Menu](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupMenu) and inflate custom layout in this to get your expected result.
This is a [reference blog](https://www.androhub.com/android-popup-menu/) for this, have a look.

or, there are also third-party libraries available
https://github.com/skydoves/PowerMenu

**Feel free to ask if something is unclear.**

Comment: Glad to help you.